# Langchain routerchain gives OutputParserException

Tags: python, langchain

I'm using langchain to define an application that first identifies the type of question coming in (=detected_intent) and then uses a routerchain to identify which prompt template to use to answer this type of question. When running my routerchain I get an error:

"OutputParserException: Parsing text
OfferInquiry
raised following error:
Got invalid JSON object. Error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

- detected_intent is a string with a value 'OfferInquiry'
- destinations_str is a string with value: 'OfferInquiry\nSalesOrder\nOrderStatusRequest\nRepairRequest'
- user_query= 'Ik ben op zoek naar een laptop'

> ```
> MULTI_PROMPT_ROUTER_TEMPLATE = """
> Select the right prompt best suited to answer the customer's question. You can select the 
> prompt candidate from the list of candidate prompts given below. 
>
> <<CUSTOMER's question>>
> {{user_query}}
>
> <<DETECTED intent>>
> {detected_intent}
>
> << CANDIDATE PROMPTS >>
> {destinations_list}
>
> << OUTPUT>>"""
>
>
> router_template = MULTI_PROMPT_ROUTER_TEMPLATE.format(
>     destinations_list=destinations_str, detected_intent=detected_intent
> )
> router_prompt = PromptTemplate(
>     template=router_template,
>     input_variables=['user_query'],
>     output_parser=RouterOutputParser(),
> )
>
> router_chain = LLMRouterChain.from_llm(llm, router_prompt)
>
> chain = MultiPromptChain(router_chain=router_chain,  #input to destination choice
>                          destination_chains=destination_chains,  #prompts per destination 
>                          default_chain=default_chain, verbose=True
>                         )
> chain.run(user_query)
> ```

The complete error log is:

> Error in on_chain_start callback: 'name'
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\output_parsers\json.py
> in parse_and_check_json_markdown(text, expected_keys)
> 31     try:
> ---> 32         json_obj = parse_json_markdown(text)
> 33     except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\output_parsers\json.py
> in parse_json_markdown(json_string)
> 24     # Parse the JSON string into a Python dictionary
> ---> 25     parsed = json.loads(json_str)
> 26
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\json_*init*_.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook,
> parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
> 345             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
> --> 346         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
> 347     if cls is None:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
> 336         """
> --> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> 338         end = _w(s, end).end()
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
> 354         except StopIteration as err:
> --> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> 356         return obj, end
>
> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> OutputParserException                     Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\chains\router\llm_router.py
> in parse(self, text)
> 95             expected_keys = ["destination", "next_inputs"]
> ---> 96             parsed = parse_and_check_json_markdown(text, expected_keys)
> 97             if not isinstance(parsed["destination"], str):
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\output_parsers\json.py
> in parse_and_check_json_markdown(text, expected_keys)
> 33     except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
> ---> 34         raise OutputParserException(f"Got invalid JSON object. Error: {e}")
> 35     for key in expected_keys:
>
> OutputParserException: Got invalid JSON object. Error: Expecting
> value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> OutputParserException                     Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17900\3933904922.py in 
> 1 #Test bovenstaande uit
> 2 #chain.run(user_query)
> ----> 3 chain.run('Ik ben op zoek naar een laptop')
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py
> in run(self, callbacks, *args, **kwargs)
> 256             if len(args) != 1:
> 257                 raise ValueError("`run` supports only one positional argument.")
> --> 258             return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks)[self.output_keys[0]]
> 259
> 260         if kwargs and not args:
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py
> in **call**(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks,
> include_run_info)
> 145         except (KeyboardInterrupt, Exception) as e:
> 146             run_manager.on_chain_error(e)
> --> 147             raise e
> 148         run_manager.on_chain_end(outputs)
> 149         final_outputs: Dict[str, Any] = self.prep_outputs(
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py
> in **call**(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks,
> include_run_info)
> 139         try:
> 140             outputs = (
> --> 141                 self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
> 142                 if new_arg_supported
> 143                 else self._call(inputs)
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\chains\router\base.py
> in _call(self, inputs, run_manager)
> 80         _run_manager = run_manager or CallbackManagerForChainRun.get_noop_manager()
> 81         callbacks = _run_manager.get_child()
> ---> 82         route = self.router_chain.route(inputs, callbacks=callbacks)
> 83
> 84         _run_manager.on_text(
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\chains\router\base.py
> in route(self, inputs, callbacks)
> 28
> 29     def route(self, inputs: Dict[str, Any], callbacks: Callbacks = None) -> Route:
> ---> 30         result = self(inputs, callbacks=callbacks)
> 31         return Route(result["destination"], result["next_inputs"])
> 32
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py
> in **call**(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks,
> include_run_info)
> 145         except (KeyboardInterrupt, Exception) as e:
> 146             run_manager.on_chain_error(e)
> --> 147             raise e
> 148         run_manager.on_chain_end(outputs)
> 149         final_outputs: Dict[str, Any] = self.prep_outputs(
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py
> in **call**(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks,
> include_run_info)
> 139         try:
> 140             outputs = (
> --> 141                 self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
> 142                 if new_arg_supported
> 143                 else self._call(inputs)
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\chains\router\llm_router.py
> in _call(self, inputs, run_manager)
> 58         output = cast(
> 59             Dict[str, Any],
> ---> 60             self.llm_chain.predict_and_parse(callbacks=callbacks, **inputs),
> 61         )
> 62         return output
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\chains\llm.py
> in predict_and_parse(self, callbacks, **kwargs)
> 241         result = self.predict(callbacks=callbacks, **kwargs)
> 242         if self.prompt.output_parser is not None:
> --> 243             return self.prompt.output_parser.parse(result)
> 244         else:
> 245             return result
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain\chains\router\llm_router.py
> in parse(self, text)
> 111             return parsed
> 112         except Exception as e:
> --> 113             raise OutputParserException(
> 114                 f"Parsing text\n{text}\n raised following error:\n{e}"
> 115             )
>
> OutputParserException: Parsing text OfferInquiry  raised following
> error: Got invalid JSON object. Error: Expecting value: line 1 column
> 1 (char 0)

Comment: Resolved in adding in my prompt template the resulting output should be displayed as a json format